# About page language and wording (omission of moderator?)

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, about-page

On the [About](https://patents.stackexchange.com/about) page I was checking out the awesome new formatting (very nicely done, including how much of it is straight text)

---

I'm looking at this cute guy here:

http://sstatic.net/patents/img/about-guy-comment.png

And all around it, all I can think is

> what if people *do* make mean comments?

And then I see:

http://sstatic.net/patents/img/about-mod-power.png

and I think

> ehwut? mod-like? saywhat?

---

I'm trying to think like a non-stacker, someone who has no appreciation of the website. They should know that there are community moderators looking out for things and trying to be generally helpful, but that they are merely janitors, and that at the end of the day the site governs itself, so by your participation you're becoming an unofficial moderator, or something like that.

I just feel like that part is missing. Obviously I know a thing or two about the network, but trying to read this as a non-user I feel like this very important part is missing ...

[image]

Comment: Good feedback. This was a very rushed version for this site.  Expect to see an updated version before we go live.

Comment: +1 Any perspective on what new users need to see to get started is a big help.

Answer (score 5):

This is the first public iteration of a new introductory text for these sites. We'll be tweaking the wording, format, and so on - but right now, it's important to focus on the basic information necessary to dive in and use the site. Adding information on moderators can probably wait until we actually *have* moderators here - for the short term, things that can't be handled by the community will be dealt with by the Stack Exchange staff (as is the case with all early beta sites).

Of course, more detailed information on the use of the site can, as always, be found in [the site FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#flagging).

Comment: Very true, like I said, looking for the parts that stuck out to me as someone who had never been here before. Obviously I expect most people familiar to SE to just gloss it over. Loving the format tho, and all the site-bits.